# how to show image in angularjs on mouseover?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to zoom image on `mouseover` in angularjs one more thing my image source is `dynamic` so I will not set it on `background`.
I found a way to zoom on mouse over
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGJJeB
Same thing I want to do in angularjs I tried like this
https://plnkr.co/edit/CluSwaohUQbsveSPNz9L?p=preview

```
#overlay{
  border:1px solid black;
  width:350px;
  height:300px;
  display:inline-block;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;

}
```

I don't want to set background static image it should be dynamic .

Comment: If you know how to do it with background image you could change background image with javascript.

Comment: hmm yes please see my update plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/CluSwaohUQbsveSPNz9L?p=preview

Comment: but my zoom image is not updated when I move my cursor to actual image

Comment: see  the similar Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54113322/why-image-not-change-when-user-mouse-over-to-image