# why image not change when user mouse over to image?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to zoom the image on mouseover of image.When I tried first time it show my `zoomed image` on `overlay`.But when I change my cursor position 
`overlay` or zoom image not show updated image why ?
here is my code
https://plnkr.co/edit/CluSwaohUQbsveSPNz9L?p=preview

```
 $scope.zoomIn= function(event) {
  var element = document.getElementById("overlay");
  element.style.display = "inline-block";
  element.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+$scope.img+')'
  var img = document.getElementById("imgZoom");
  var posX = event.offsetX ? (event.offsetX) : event.pageX - img.offsetLeft;
  var posY = event.offsetY ? (event.offsetY) : event.pageY - img.offsetTop;
  element.style.backgroundPosition=(-posX*2)+"px "+(-posY*4)+"px";
   // $scope.$apply();
}

 $scope.zoomOut= function() {
  var element = document.getElementById("overlay");
  element.style.display = "none";
    //  $scope.$apply();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your event not focuses **because you are not using angularjs's triggered events**
instead of onmousemove use **ng-mousemove** and instead of onmouseout use **ng-mouseout**

and in your called functions try to use only angularjs functions, **by using pure javascript you are risking to broke angular's scope**

here a working version

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  
   $scope.zoomIn= function(event) {
  var element = document.getElementById("overlay");
  element.style.display = "inline-block";
  element.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+$scope.img+')'
  var img = document.getElementById("imgZoom");
  var posX = event.offsetX ? (event.offsetX) : event.pageX - img.offsetLeft;
  var posY = event.offsetY ? (event.offsetY) : event.pageY - img.offsetTop;
  element.style.backgroundPosition=(-posX*2)+"px "+(-posY*4)+"px";
   // $scope.$apply();
}

 $scope.zoomOut= function() {
  var element = document.getElementById("overlay");
  element.style.display = "none";
    //  $scope.$apply();
}
  $scope.img = 'http://ginger-mum.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/3633-1269758855-0da5042c33400a811a5d766be4579cb8.jpg';
});
```

```css
/* Put your css in here */

#overlay{
  border:1px solid black;
  width:350px;
  height:300px;
  display:inline-block;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
<img id="imgZoom" 
width="300px" 
height="200px" 
ng-mousemove="zoomIn($event)" 
ng-mouseout="zoomOut()" 
src="{{img}}">
<br/>
<div id="overlay" ng-mousemove="zoomIn(event)"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I am using mg-mousemove event https://plnkr.co/edit/CluSwaohUQbsveSPNz9L?p=preview

Comment: "pure javascript you are risking to broke angular's scope" so how I will achieve this without core javascript

Comment: @user5711656 ok, now you replaced with ng-mouse{Events} I noted that if you replace your ng-mouseover with ng-mousemove all works perfecly

Comment: @user5711656 did you see it?

Comment: can you please share plunker link